# Save data from a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have this loop that fetches prices from an array and passes it to int, but I don't know how to save the data. I tried saving them in the localstorage, but it only saves me a single "value".I need the data outside the loop to sum it up and store it in `useState`. HElP!

```
const totalPreciosArr = Array.from(totalPrecios)
            // console.log(totalPrecios)
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPreciosArr.length; i++) {
                const gg = totalPreciosArr[i]
                const gg2 = Number.parseFloat(gg)
                console.log(gg2)
            }
```

Comment: As is, every iteration of your loop redeclares gg and gg2, so they are reset. If you need either of those outside of the loop, define them at a higher scope (using `let` instead of `const` and assign them inside the loop as you're doing

Comment: If you're looking to sum the prices, consider using `Array.reduce()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sum of prices is what you need?

```js
totalPrecios=[100.34, 120.98, 130.77, 150.99]
const totalPreciosArr = totalPrecios.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc + curr
})

console.log(Math.round(totalPreciosArr * 100) / 100)
```